# SDE.ST_INTERSECTS fails to find point

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, st-geometry

The following query fails to find a point that is less than 3 meters from the buffered point:

```
SELECT NODE_ID FROM ZLEVEL
WHERE SDE.ST_INTERSECTS(
    ZLEVEL.SHAPE,
    SDE.ST_BUFFER(SDE.ST_POINT(527152.8261, 422964.9258, 31), 115.0)) = 1;
```

The point that can't be found has coordinates `(527152.47980000, 422962.29100000)`. Changing its coordinates very slightly to `(527153.47980000, 422963.29100000)` causes it to be found by `ST_INTERSECTS`.

We have tried rebuilding the spatial index to no avail. Any thoughts? We are using ArcSDE 9.3.1 on Oracle 11g.

**Edit:**

```
SELECT SRID
FROM SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'ZLEVEL'

  SRID
------
    31

SELECT SDE.ST_SRID(SHAPE)
FROM ZLEVEL
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;

                 SDE.ST_SRID(SHAPE)
-----------------------------------
                                 31
```

Comment: What is the precision of your shape field? http://www.esf.edu/for/herrington/557/notes/precision.htm

Comment: What is SRID used by the ZLEVEL feature class?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall That documentation is outdated, even with an ancient build like 9.3.1.  HIGH precision (54 bits) has been the default since ArcGIS 9.2, but that doc states that coordinates are restricted to 2^31 discrete values (BASIC precision).  The process is the same, but the divisor is now MUCH larger (the `long long` used has more precision than the `double` mantissa)

Comment: @Vince The SRID is 31. See edit above.